# Vacuum packed salmon fillet (non-smoked) sat in fridge that turned off for undetermined amount of time. Can it still be eaten?

Tags: salmon, vacuum

As the title says: the vacuum packed salmon fillets have been sitting in a turned off fridge for quite some hours. The packs only felt a little cooler than the room temperature of +/- 20 degrees Celsius (68℉). They have been put in a working fridge immediately after finding out. If they weren't vacuum packed, I'd have thrown them away already.

Can I still safely eat them if they do not smell bad, or should I throw them out?

Comment: Vacuum packing does not play a role here.

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate of that @moscafj as it wasn't stored at room temperature. However it would still be worth reading as some of it is applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I came across the same post. It does somewhat apply, however they do not specificly talk about vacuum sealed perishable food. That's why I thought about asking the question (and because I prefer not to throw out salmon fillets haha).

Comment: @GdD if the OP doesn't know exactly how long a product has been in the danger zone, he/she has to assume that the answers in the linked question apply.

Comment: I wouldn't make that assumption myself @moscafj, I think this is sufficiently different to warrant an answer.